# Date not showing correct for condition

Tags: php, html, date

I am creating a timesheet, where it checks for previous date.

The condition is that the timesheet will show date of today and yesterday. If today is monday, it should show yesterday's date as friday, not sunday.

But its not working. The code is :

```
$dateToday = date('d-M-Y');
$datePrevious = date("d-M-Y", strtotime((date('D') == 'MON' ? "-3 day" : "-1 day")));
```

But its not working. Please help me where I went wrong ?

Its showing for monday and sunday.

Comment: The string "not working" is not a built-in error message in PHP.

Comment: strtoupper that date('D') if you want to compare in all caps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Mon` not `MON` for the comparison of `date('D')` because the string comparison is case sensitive and `date('D')` returns lowecase with the first character uppercase.

```
$dateToday = date('d-M-Y');
$datePrevious = date("d-M-Y", strtotime((date('D') == 'Mon' ? "-3 day" : "-1 day")));
```

Alternatively you could use `date('w') == '1'`.